# What is the purpose of the buffer when we can store in a string variable?

Tags: go

Why would I want to use a buffer when I can just concatenate strings?

**PSEUDO CODE BELOW**

```
var buffer bytes.Buffer 
for i := 0; i < 200; i++ {
    buffer.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(i))
}
fmt.Println(buffer.String())
```

Vs

```
buffer := ""
for i := 0; i < 200; i++ {
    buffer += strconv.Itoa(i)
}
fmt.Println(buffer)
```

Comment: Sidenote - add `strconv` for second example.

Comment: Neither of your code blocks work.

Comment: @AdamSmith It's untested code. I wasn't expecting people to run it, just threw it together to illustrate my point.

Comment: @Hardworker But your question asks "Why use a buffer when I can just use a variable," and for illustration you use a variable that *doesn't work*. The answer to that question is "Using a variable doesn't work, as your own example shows."

Comment: @AdamSmith You've never seen someone post pseudo code before to make a point? Isn't it immediately obvious the code is incomplete and just trying to illustrate something?

Comment: @Hardworker I have seem many uses of pseudo code.  In most cases, the pseudo-ness of the code is worse than posting real code that actually works.  There are a few exceptions, but the above is not one of them.  (Examples include situations where the underlying language makes the operation in question extremely awkward, or where you are casually chatting next to a whiteboard and the cost of ensuring code is valid is high, and when you are doing a polished presentation where you have written valid code, then intentionally removed unimportant bits.)

Comment: I edited the post to make clear that the code is not actual complete code, it's totally true that was not clear if it was or not real code. I think that like this the post can stay since the question is valid, could be recurring to other users, and has already good answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A buffer grows in chunks to amortize memory allocations.

Because strings are immutable, every iteration through the loop must allocate a new string.

Answer (score 3):

You can see a buffer as a queue where you place things in line. Everyone just shoves in line one behind the other, it's very efficient and doesn't take up extra space to add new items. You just insert them and you are done.

So when you add A, B, C, D,E to a buffer the operation will look kinda like this memory wise:

```
buffer=A
buffer=A|B
buffer=A|B|C
buffer=A|B|C|D
buffer=A|B|C|D|E
```

Now, if you concatenate strings, a lot of memory will have to be allocated and reallocated

```
 str=''
 str=Allocate(A),allocate(str+A),deallocate(str='')
 str=Allocate(B),allocate(str(''|A)+B),deallocate(str=''|A)
 str=Allocate(C),allocate(str(''|A|B)+C),deallocate(str=''|A|B)
 str=Allocate(D),allocate(str(''|A|B|C)+D),deallocate(str=''|A|B|C)
 str=Allocate(E),allocate(str(''|A|B|C|D)+E),deallocate(str=''|A|B|C|D)
```

As you can see, by constantly adding to the string a new string as to be created, composed of the old string, then the new string is made and the old string gets deallocated.
This causes a lot of junk memory. When you add in a buffer you just neatly line up everything without taking up to much extra memory.

Whilst if you concatenate the strings, you are constantly assigning newer and bigger variables.
Oldstring + append string + new concat string. and this grows and grows and grows.
If you have a big file you read line by line this might give some out of memory errors after a while.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Go. So the second example will allocate a new string on each iteration, so will have O(n^2) runtime.